# AutoMapper complex nested mappings

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, projection

I've read [this example on AutoMapper's GitHub](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html), but the example assumes there'll only be one way to map InnerSource, ever:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>();
Mapper.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerDest>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var source = new OuterSource
    {
        Value = 5,
        Inner = new InnerSource {OtherValue = 15}
    };

var dest = Mapper.Map<OuterSource, OuterDest>(source);
```

With my project, I'm serializing objects created with EF that have circular references. The reason for this is I will need to come at the objects from different 'directions.' For example, if I ask for a list of users, I want to see the projects they're associated with. If I ask for a project, I want to see the users associated with that project.

These circular references can get fairly deep, like `User.Role.Project.TaskTime.User`, `User.TaskTime.Project.Task.TaskType.VisibleToRole.Role.User`, etc.

So I need the nested mapping to be fairly deep, and the way it's done depends on what the first mapping was.

Currently I'm doing:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserFull>()
    .ForMember("TaskTimes", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<ICollection<TaskTime>, UserTaskTime>(src.TaskTimes)));
Mapper.CreateMap<TaskTime, UserTaskTime>()
    .ForMember("Task", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<Task, UserTaskTimeTask>(src.Task)));
//...
```

The viewmodels for that snippet look like this:

```
public class UserFull
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TaskTime> TaskTimes { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class UserTaskTime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Task Task { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class UserTaskTimeTask
{
    //...
}
```

Is this right? Should I be projecting each member from the viewmodel and mapping it by hand using projection? Or is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Are you using automapper to map values from ViewModel to your DB entities? I would strongly advice not to use AutoMapper for these purposes and do it manually, otherwise you will end up with complicated mapper profiles that will keep failing if you add new entities that use old ones for mapping.

Comment: @CarsonMyers Since this is one of [your Famous Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=84478) and you had a solution, do add an answer.

Comment: @aaron I would love to, unfortunately it's been too long; this was a university project, I haven't used EF or C# since then and I don't know how to find the original code. I may come back to this and see if I can reproduce it a bit later

Comment: @Carson - I am currently in the same boat.  I have a class library that serves as a 'data layer' and uses an EF core DbContext.  This class library more or less follows the repository pattern, and its methods take and return POCO objects that serve as models used by a consuming application, in my case its an API project.  I'm looking at using Automapper but cant bring myself to justify setting up overly complex map configurations compared to simply projecting the results of the EF queries into these model classes.